# Error: Cannot find module './grunt/config' when building on TravisCI

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, travis-ci

TravisCI is throwing an error when trying to run tests for my application. However, it works fine on my local. Until recently the `node_modules` folder was in the .gitignore so wasn't in the repository. Therefore TravisCI ran `npm install` to install all the modules. But since I've committed `node_modules` this is the error that is appearing:

```
Error: Cannot find module './grunt/config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at gRequire (/home/travis/build/fender/dmeapp/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:23:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/fender/dmeapp/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:39:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

You can see the full travis build here:
https://travis-ci.org/fender/dmeapp/builds/29427422

And this is the code repository if you need to see the Gruntfile etc:
https://github.com/fender/dmeapp

Any insight into what's happening here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you excluded or accidentially deleted the `config.js` file at `node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/`. Compare your folder with the [Grunt source repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/tree/master/lib/grunt).

Comment: Thank you! I had `config.js` in my .gitignore but I only wanted to ignore that file in the root directory. I changed this to `/config.js` .